# Vue.js Atualizar dados da minha tabela

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Possuo uma tabela que é preenchida no momento que carrega minha tela, nessa tabela tenho listados todas as minhas correções, tenho uma ação de delete para essa correção, ele deleta certinho porque quando atualizo a tela com o F5 o dado não esta mais lá, mas eu queria que quando o usuário deletasse o valor já sumisse. Porem nessa mesma janela tenho uma outra tabela de redações e ai tem que aparecer nessa janela a redação que antes pertencia a essa correção.

Por isso tava tentando fazer ele forçar a carregar a tela de novo. Como faço isso?

```
<b-table
  :data="redacaos[1]"
  :paginated="true"
  :per-page="10"
  :hoverable="true"
  :checkable="true"
>
  <template slot-scope="props">
    <!-- colunas-->

    <b-table-column
      label="Corrigida em"
    >{{ formatData(props.row.created_at, 'DD/MM/YYYY - HH:MM') }}</b-table-column>

    <b-table-column label="Número Da Redação">{{ props.row.redacao.numero }}</b-table-column>

    <b-table-column label="Aluno">{{ props.row.redacao.aluno.name }}</b-table-column>

    <b-table-column label="Proposta">{{ props.row.proposta }}</b-table-column>

    <b-table-column label="Grade">{{ props.row.grade }}</b-table-column>

    <b-table-column label="Escola">{{ props.row.redacao.escola }}</b-table-column>

    <b-table-column label="Nota Final">{{ props.row.nota_final }}</b-table-column>

    <b-table-column field="actions" label="Ações" width="180" centered>
      <!-- detalhes -->
      <b-tooltip label="Detalhes" position="is-top" type="is-dark">
        <button
          class="button is-primary is-round"
          id="info"
          @click="correcaoInfo(props.row.id), isCardModalActive2 = true"
        >
          <b-icon icon="eye"></b-icon>
        </button>
      </b-tooltip>

      <!-- deletar -->
      <b-tooltip label="Deletar" position="is-top" type="is-dark">
        <button
          class="button is-primary is-round"
          id="delete"
          @click="deletarCorrecao(props.row.id)"
        >
          <b-icon icon="delete-outline"></b-icon>
        </button>
      </b-tooltip>
    </b-table-column>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

função de deletar correção:

```
deletarCorrecao(cuuid) {
      if (confirm("Você realmente deseja excluir essa correção?")) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        CorrecaoService.Delete(cuuid)
          .then(() => {
            this.$buefy.toast.open({
              duration: 5000,
              message: "Deleção realizado com sucesso!",
              position: "is-top-right",
              type: "is-success"
            });
            this.$router.push({ name: 'admin/redacao', params: { }});
          })
          .catch(() => {})
          .finally(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
          });
      }
    },
```

Comment: A sua função que faz o load das informações está dentro do created ? Se sim, isola ela em um método separado, e no momento do @click do delete, tu chama a função do search novamente.
Caso ela esteja em outro método, tu podes enviar um this.$emit('reload'), para o componente que tem a responsabilidade de executar essa query.

Comment: Rodrigo Nantes muito obrigado, relamente muito simples e solucionou o que eu precisava.